# jq: map arrays to csv field headers

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

Is there a way to export a json like this:

```json
{
   "id":"2261026",
   "meta":{
      "versionId":"1",
      "lastUpdated":"2021-11-08T15:13:39.318+01:00",
   },
   "address": [
      "string-value1",
      "string-value2"
   ],
   "identifier":[
      {
         "system":"urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.93",
         "value":"6209"
      },
      {
         "system":"urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2",
         "value":"00042"
      },
      {
         "system":"urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.90",
         "value":"UAB2"
      }
   ]
}
{
   "id":"2261027",
   "meta":{
      "versionId":"1",
      "lastUpdated":"2021-11-08T15:13:39.318+01:00",
   },
   "address": [
      "string-value1",
      "string-value2",
      "string-value3",
      "string-value4"
   ],
   "identifier":[
      {
         "system":"urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.93",
         "value":"6205"
      },
      {
         "system":"urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2",
         "value":"05041"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd like to get something like this:

```csv
"id","meta_versionId","meta_lastUpdated","address","identifier0_system","identifier0_value","identifier1_system","identifier1_value","identifier2_system","identifier2_value"
"2261026","1","2021-11-08T15:13:39.318+01:00","string-value1|string-value2","urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.93","6209","urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2","00042","urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.90","UAB2"
"2261027","1","2021-11-08T15:13:39.318+01:00","string-value1|string-value2|string-value3|string-value4","urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.93","6205","urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.20.2","05041",,
```

In short:

`address` array field string values has to be mapped joining its values using "|" character. Example: `"string-value1|string-value2"`

`identifiers` array field objects have to be mapped to `"n-field-header"`. Example: `"identifier0_system","identifier0_value","identifier1_system","identifier1_value","identifier2_system","identifier2_value,..."`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```sh
jq -r '[
  .id,
  (.meta | .versionId, .lastUpdated),
  (.address | join("|")),
  (.identifier[] | .system, .value)
] | @csv'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JIvlj8TdSG)

---

To prepend a header row with the number of `identifierX_system` and `identifierX_value` field pairs in it matching the length of the input's longest `identifier` array, try this

```sh
jq -rs '[
  
  "id",
  "meta_versionId", "meta_lastUpdated",
  "address",
  (
    range([.[].identifier | length] | max)
    | "identifier\(.)_system", "identifier\(.)_value"
  )

], (.[] | [

  .id,
  (.meta | .versionId, .lastUpdated),
  (.address | join("|")),
  (.identifier[] | .system, .value)

]) | @csv'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/quifX4aOfQ)

Comment: Is there a way to add headers automatically?

Comment: How many pairs of `identifierX_system` and `identifierX_value` should the header contain?

Comment: At most 4, at least 2

Comment: But what does it depend on? If the number is a constant, simply write out the full header and add it as a first array. For a variable number (e.g. the maximum length across all `identifier` arrays) you should read the input either using `[inputs]` (or use the `-s` option) and put it in a variable; then calculate your desired amount and generate the header array accordingly; finally, feed the input array variable's content into what we have already.

Comment: Don't quite figure out. Do you mean: `(.identifier[0:3] | .system, .value)`?

Comment: Something along the lines of `[inputs] as $in | ([$in[].identifier | length] | max) as $max | $in[] | ...`. Sorry, gotta go now, will look at it later....

Comment: Back again, edited my answer for a version with dynamic headers (matching the longest `identifier` array).